# Omit null value when DE-serializing json file

Tags: java, deserialization, objectmapper

I have a `student.json` and `Student.java` as follows:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;

    private String age;
}

[{"name": "John", "age": 18}, {"name": "Alex"}]
```

I read the json file and map to `List<Student>` as follows:

```
File inRulesFile = (new ClassPathResource("Student.json")).getFile();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(inRulesFile, Student[].class));
```

So the output is `[{John - 18},{Alex - null}]`
I don't want DE-serialize null value. How can I do this?

Comment: Deserialize it like normal and the filter the resulting list. No sense in adding complexity to the former.

Comment: I know but I want to ignore null value and don't allow it to map to Student object if it is null due to personal reason.

Comment: the feature in jackson to omit null values is just for serialisation, for deserialisation there is no such feature, you have to filter the list after reading

Comment: If neither Jackson nor your code sets the age, then it is null by default.  If you don’t want to see that, change the toString method of Student (or whatever code you’re using to print the Student instances).  By the way, getFile() will fail if you try to run this program as a .jar file, because entries inside .jar files are just compressed data, not actual files.